# Backbone.js Views bound to external model

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Say `ListTwoItemView` which is used to represent model `ListTwoItem`, and that `ListTwoItem` holds the ID of a `ListOneItem` to which it is linked.

If the user deletes a `ListOneItem`, all `ListTwoItem`'s that link to it should be deleted. Does it make sense if I bind the `ListTwoItemView` to the linked `ListOneItem` so that should the referenced item be deleted - the `ListTwoItem` model and view are also both removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. Models do not know about views. What you normally do in that case is that your ListOneItem will destroy your ListTwoItem when it is destroyed itself.

This will raise a "delete" event on the collection the ListTwoItem is part of (if it is not part of anything, you must trigger an event yourself). Listen to that event and remove/rerender the view as needed.

Comment: what about if I bind the ListTwoItem to the ListOneItem, and will destroy itself when the ListOneItem is destroyed? That way the link is always established and the ListOneItem doesn't need to be aware of the ListTwoItem collection, nor does it have to cycle through all ListTwoItem's and delete any that reference itself.